# Keep SQL Server up to date with MS Access database values

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I am working on taking continuous data from a machine, such as air pressure, temperature, etc, which is stored in MS Access databases and syncing it up with an SQL database where I can access it and pass it to a data historian such as OSISoft PI.

I have already used the import/export functionality through ODBC connections to transfer the data from the MS Access databases to my SQL database, but this data is not continuously updated. I would need to run this tool every ~ 15 - 20 seconds to keep the data up to date which I feel there must be an easier way.

I need a way of passing the continuously updating data in my MS Access databases to a SQL server where it can be stored and managed for later use.

Comment: My first thought would be to write a manual ETL script to move the data, then put that script in a SQL Agent job and schedule it to run as needed.

Comment: This could involve timer code behind a form. Timer is resource hog. Your question is too broad. Do research and when you have code with issue, post question.

Comment: I would just use an external table in access. In other words the table is the sql server table. Then you don't need to synch it or make multiple copies of it. Both Access and sql server use the same table.

Comment: ^^ this, i.e. link the table from Sql Server in Access. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-sql-server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e

Comment: SQL Server is MUCH more robust than Access.  Why can't you dump the data directly into SQL Server, and eliminate Access from the equation?

Comment: I know, the manufacturer of the machine has created an on-board system which uses Access databases. A report is returned after the machine has run its course but we want to get the data directly from the machine as it is running not just in a report at the end. So accessing the on-board Access databases is required.

Comment: Create an SSIS job and then schedule it to run with SQL Server agent. Should be simple enough to do and you won't need any additional licenses

Comment: Try replace the acces tables with linked sql server tables (use same name)m then run your code and the linked tables. Usually doesn't need much changes.

Comment: After some testing I don't think it is possible to access the Access Databases while the machine is running so this idea possibly won't work.

Comment: Your "Machine", is an embedded device, with an ms-access backend? And the "Machine" opens the backend in exclusive-mode ? Name the "Machine", maybe someone has experience.